# Is there any method to exit the main shell before the subshell returns?

Tags: bash

As all we know, in bash, if we start  a process, "bash another.sh" for example, main bash will wait for another.sh to finished, then execute the remained code in main bash, Is there any method to exit the main shell before another.sh returns?

Comment: nohup is a better way...log out safely !! It sends the standard output of the command to the nohup.out

Comment: Do you mean `exec another.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to log out of the shell before the process has finished you can prepend [xls's statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10494406/885443) with [nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup):

```
nohup bash another.sh &
```

Then your newly started process won't receive `SIGHUP` when logging out and will continue to run in the background.

Comment: after prepend the 'nohup', it does not execute another.sh,why?

Comment: What output do you get in the terminal? It should say something like `[1] 3135`which is the `PID` of the process, and also `appending output to nohup.out`.

Comment: It just says nohup:appending output to 'nohup.out'

Comment: I guess your process has started then. Take a look in `nohup.out` (with e.g. `less nohup.out`) to see what it outputs (if `another.sh` outputs anything that is). You can also take a look at your running processes with `top` or `ps` (see the `man` pages for more info).

Comment: oh yes, it has. thank you. truly it exit before the sub shell returns . but it doesn't work with my original purpose. my original purpose is to start a bash script to kill process python(which is executing somefile.py), and then restart somefile.py, but it seems that bash will take place of somefile.py to listen on the tcp port, and somefile.py can not listen to it again. But it is another question. Thank you for your kindness.